# MVC3 Display all records from Table on View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2012

I have a BookingView class in Model:

```
public class BookingView
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Attraction")]
    public int Attraction { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Date")]
    public string Date { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Username")]
    public string Username { get; set; }
}
```

Table against this model in DB is `Tickets`.

I need to write a function in another class in model named `BookingManager` to get all Ticket Records.

```
public IEnumerable<BookingView> GetAllBookings()
{
    var a = from o in dre.Tickets select o;
    return a.ToList();
}
```

I want to display these records in view named `ViewAllBookings`:

```
@model IEnumerable<VirtualTickets.Models.ViewModel.BookingView>

@{
  ViewBag.Title = "ViewAllBookings";
}

<h2>ViewAllBookings</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table>
<tr>
    <th>
        Attraction
    </th>
    <th>
        Date
    </th>
    <th>
        Username
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Attraction)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Date)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Username)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
    </td>
</tr>
}

</table>
```

The function gives complie time error in function `GetAllBookings` on return statement. If I change return type to `Ticket` then I get runtime error as expected because in view `ViewAllBookings` it is expecting IEnumerable List of records having type `BookingView`.

Please provide a solution to this situation. I am really confused how to deal with this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your setup requires converting the entity class `Ticket` into the view model `BookingView`.  I guess you need something like this:

```
return a.AsEnumerable().Select(ticket => new BookingView 
    {
        Attraction = ticket.SomeProperty,
        // etc
    })
.ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to write method that maps Ticket to BookingView and use it like this:

```
public IEnumerable<BookingView> GetAllBookings()
{
    var a = from o in dre.Tickets select o;
    return a.AsEnumerable().Select(Map).ToList();
}

private BookingView Map(Ticket ticket)
{
    var bookingView = new BookingView();
    //mapping code goes here
    return bookingView;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if your `Tickets` table actually has the same columns as the `BookingView` class in your code, but if theere's a mapping between the table and your class, your solution would be:

```
var a = from o in dre.Tickets 
         select new BookingView  { Attraction= o.Attraction, 
                                   Date=o.Date, 
                                   Username = o.UserName } ;
return a.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is obvious that you are getting this error because you are returning a `Ticket` object and your view needs a list of `BookingView` objects. The 2 don't match, i.e. they are not the same.

Your `BookingManager` should return your tickets to the controller. Here is an alternative way of how I would have done it.

You could change your view model to look like this:

```
public class BookingViewModel
{
     public List<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; }
}
```

Your `BookingManager` can contain the following method to return your tickets:

```
public class BookingManager : IBookingManager
{
     // References to your database context

     public IEnumerable<Ticket> GetAllTickets()
     {
          return databaseContext.Tickets;
     }
}
```

In your booking controller you can inject an instance of `IBookingManager` with a `dependency injection framework` like `AutoFac`:

```
public class BookingController : Controller
{
     private readonly IBookingManager bookingManager;

     public BookingController(IBookingManager bookingManager)
     {
          this.bookingManager = bookingManager;
     }

     public ActionResult Index()
     {
          BookingViewModel viewModel = new BookingViewModel
          {
               Tickets = bookingManager.GetAllTickets().ToList()
          };

          return View(viewModel);
     }
}
```

And then on your view:

```
@model YourProject.ViewModels.Tickets.BookingViewModel

@foreach (var ticket in Model.Tickets)
{
     // Display ticket details here
}
```

I hope this helps.